# Requiring/Implementing Bluetooth PassKey PassCode on Client Device

Tags: bluetooth

Is there a way in iOS or Android to set up a Bluetooth passkey passcode whenever another device wants to connect to my device via Bluetooth?

My application involves a BLE client connecting to a BLE server and the two devices will transmit data between each other. However, the data transmitted will be very sensitive security-wise. So beyond the standard encryption my goal is to not initiate data transmission until both devices have authenticated each other (e.g., with a passkey).

It seems like a Bluetooth passkey is something set up by the device manufacturer and not something able to be configured by the user. If so and there is no passkey pairing, would an acceptable alternative be to require a passkey to be exchanged (after the devices are paired) before the devices can transmit any sensitive data?

Comment: Are both devices (client and server) iOS/Android devices, or is one device an embedded device and the other iOS/Android?

Comment: In my specific use case I am designing for the server is a BLE microcontroller embedded inside a wearable device. The client will always be a mobile device. But I am wondering for testing whether BLE passkeys can be turned on for mobile devices in both cases that both devices are mobile devices and cases where only the client is a mobile device, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On a Android phone, assuming the phone is GATT server (which provides data for a client device to read), you can safeguard that data held in a characteristic by setting its read permission to `PERMISSION_READ_ENCRYPTED_MITM` .

For example, when you create a characteristic to be registered with the Bluetooth stack in Android, you do

```java
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(YOUR_UUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ_ENCRYPTED_MITM)
```

In this way, anyone who wants to read the characteristic needs to create a secure bonding with your phone first, either by entering a passcode or compare two numerical values. The exact way for pairing is up to the Bluetooth stacks of both devices to negotiate (based on available IO on the client).

On the other hand, if the data you want to access is stored in a third remote device, and you don't need authentication (bonding/pairing) to read from it, and you cant access the firmware. Then you **can not** enforce  secure transmission unilaterally from your phone.